# Added BitBucket repo as remote on GitHub

Tags: linux, git, github, bitbucket, git-remote

I've just installed git on Ubuntu, now I want to work on my repo in BitBucket. I'm a little confused on how to do so. I can't do the following:

```
git remote add BitBucketRepo git@bitbucket.org:dir/file.git
```

As it returns the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

It clearly is pointing to a git repo, so why is it lying to me?

Also, it is worth noting I am using SSH and I have successfully paired my GitHub account to my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run this command from a local git repository (a directory in which you have run `git init` or `git clone`) - otherwise `git remote` doesn't know which local repo you want to add the remote for.

It should be as simple as `cd my-local-dir`, where `my-local-dir` is the directory containing your local (cloned) git repository.

If you don't yet have the repo available locally:

```
git clone git@github.com:...etc... my-local-dir
cd my-local-dir
git remote add ButbucketRepo git@bitbucket.org...
git push -u ButbucketRepo master
```

This will clone your code from Github into the `my-local-dir` directory, add your BitBucket repo as a remote repository, push your code up to Bitbucket and set the local `master` branch to track the BitBucket remote's `master` branch.

Tracking means that commands that involve a remote like `git push` will automatically use the BitBucket remote's `master` branch. If you don't want that behaviour, skip the -u option.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Very simple, but I'm a novice. Thanks!